# Comic/manga about a girl whose parents die, she goes to live with her aunt and uncle who are actually vampires or witches

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga

I read a book (it was definitely a comic, possibly manga) about a girl whose parents die and she goes to live with her auntie and uncle. They are actually vampires (or witches). Her cousin is mean to her and the girl wants to leave but is convinced by her uncle to stay.

Comment: When did you read it? And you might want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a little like one of the Courtney Crumrin stories by Ted Naifeh, maybe *COURTNEY CRUMRIN AND THE NIGHT THINGS* (the first mini-series in that series, published 2003)

Courtney goes to live with her uncle, who is a warlock/witch. She's initially not keen on the move, but eventually bonds closely with her uncle, and stays with him.

Here's the cover of the first issue:

[image: Courtney Crumrin and the Night Things #1 - cover]

There are differences from what you describe, but those may be explicable:

- Courtney's parents are alive, and they come to live with the uncle, too. However, they virtually ignore her, and eventually are written out and leave her with the uncle. The bond she develops with her uncle is much more significant.
- There's no cousin. Courtney is not accepted at school, so you could be thinking of one of her classmates.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what story you're talking about, I've been trying to find it for years, but the name of it is ***[Dark Moon Diary](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/74068805-dark-moon-diary-manga-volume-1)*** (2007) by Che' Gilson.

> When 15-year-old Priscilla’s parents pass away, she has nowhere to go but to here last “living” relatives in the European town of Nachtwald. Once there, she learns that not only is Nachtwald populated by ghosts, werewolves, witches and other preternatural beings, but that her relatives are vampires. Amidst the pandemonium, she turns to her diary, and slowly learns what it takes to survive a new family, new friendships, and the anxiety of high school — all while living in an unfamiliar world!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as quotes or details matching the original question, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.